# google app engine python: how to validate an email address without a proxy server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, smtplib

Trying to create an email validation without sending an email using stmplib from this link

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/

Since I haven't write any codes yet and trying to understand what is going on.

It seems like you have to use one of those paid proxy servers like mailgun. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Are there any other ways we can validate an email address?

Answer (score 2):

the used method can be implemented using this python code
you would need to install dnspython and call verify_mail(mail)

```
import re
import smtplib
import dns.resolver # from http://www.dnspython.org/

def get_mx(domain):
    for x in dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX'):
        return x.to_text().split()[1].strip('.')

def verify_mail(mail):
    domain=re.findall('@(.*)', mail)[0]
    mx=get_mx(domain)
    smtp=smtplib.SMTP(mx)
    i,m=smtp.connect(mx)
    i,m=smtp.helo()
    i,m=smtp.verify(target)
    if i==250: return True
    else:
        i,m=smtp.mail('myemail@gmail.com')
        i,m=smtp.rcpt(target)
        if i==250: return True
        else: return False

if __name__=='__main__':
    print verify_mail('banana@yahoo.com')
```

Comment: This method will not work on GAE due to the lack of socket support.

Answer (score 2):

This method is not yet supported on GAE. The method described requires you to connect to the SMTP server and ask the server if the e-mail address exists. This requires outbound socket support on GAE, which is [not yet available](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/features) (unless you are accepted through their [trusted testers program](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0)). You need outbound socket support to both do a DNS lookup query on the domain to get the SMTP server to connect to, as well as actually connecting to the SMTP server.

You should also realize that this method doesn't work across all SMTP server implementations. Some servers may not respond to these types of requests.

I think for now you'd have to roll your own implementation to work over HTTP or pay for a service that would do this for you.

**UPDATE:**

As of the 1.7.7 SDK, [Sockets API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview) has been released in experimental status. Though they explicitly prohibit connecting to port 25 (smtp) on outgoing sockets. This would greatly prohibit how many SMTP server you can connect to (over port 587) to verify a given e-mail address.